# Convert 2d array to collored image in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have 2d list of ints like this:

```
list1 = [[1, 30, 50], [21, 45, 9], [97, 321, 100]]
```

Next i am going to convert this to numpy array:

```
myarr = np.asarray(list1)
```

Next i am going to convert this to Image using PIL like this:

```
img = Image.fromarray(myarr, "I")
img.save("my.png")
```

the problem is that i dont want image in grayscale. I dont know how to convert this in to collored image. I have to use eny map function or somethig else ?

Comment: What kind of image it is? If you want a nice colormap for numeric values there is something simple in `matplotlib`. If it's a photo then it won't simply be a programming problem.

Comment: Colored images have shape `(N,M,3)`. Your list has shape `(N,M)` and therefore doesn't represent an RGB image. There is not enough information. 

You can stack the grayscale image like `np.stack((np.array(list1),)*3,-1)` in order to obtain an RGB shape, but it will still be gray.

Answer (score -2):

The way to accomplish this is with numpy

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [[1, 30, 50], [21, 45, 9], [97, 321, 100]]
list1 = np.array(list1).reshape(-1, 3)
```

And now `list1` will have the shape N x 3, where the 3 dimension is RGB. If you know the sizes of the final image, you can do

```
np.array(list1).reshape(N, M, 3)
```

and it will re-shape your array into RGB as you need. Then once you have the numpy array, you have your array in the shape of an image and can save it to PNG, etc.