# How to convert 2D array into RGB image in python?

Tags: image, image-processing, 3d, python-imaging-library, rgb

I want to convert each 2D array into RGB image and return this RGB image to another function how can I do that. I tried to do that by `PIL` and `plt` but it didn't work with me.I am trying for more than 2 weeks to find how I can do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
for c in [cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1]:
        x = np.linspace(0, 3844, len(c))
        f = interp1d(x, c)
        result.append(f(common_x))
        normalized_result = preprocessing.normalize(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solved here, remember if you want a RGB image you need 3 channels and that means a matrix with shape (NxMx3).

[Convert 2d array to collored image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974517/convert-2d-array-to-collored-image-in-python)

Cheers!

Edit:

This is an example of how you can stack your 2D arrays into a 3D one with the shape you need.

```
import numpy as np
#some random arrays i just created for test
r = np.array([3,3,3])
g = np.array([6,6,6])
b = np.array([9,9,9])
bl = np.array([12,12,12])

#create the stacked arrays
stacked = np.dstack((r,g,b,bl))

#check the shape
print(np.shape(stacked))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I saw this but it didn't work for me.I have 22 2D arrays of size(5,3844). I want to stack them to have 3D array of size (22,5,3844).I don't know how to do that

Comment: Ok if you want to stack those arrays into a 3D one you need to use numpy library. If you have your arrays now stack them using `np.dstack()`

Comment: Can I convert this 2D array into image and stack them in 3D array ??

Comment: Yes, you can convert your initial arrays of dimension (5,3844) into grayscale images, you can use this: [Converting 2D numpy array of grayscale values to a pil image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558523/converting-2d-numpy-array-of-grayscale-values-to-a-pil-image) but again, if you want a RGB image you need a NxMx3 Matrix. And yes, you can stack them after you visualize them as images, because images are mainly 2D or 3D arrays with 1 channel (grayscale) or 3 channels (RGB, LAB, HSV, etc)